# utf-8 do not work in all

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I am working on web site in php. Everything was good, already created 13 different pages but on next have a problem with some character. it wont display font characters from latin like ščć...
the code is same on every page i'm just copy paste on every page and it worked until the last one.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

The page I have problem is 99 % same like the one i create before, with some minor changes in php code for database columne. It should use same data base as one before.
Previous work, this one not

Comment: You will need to encode it.

Comment: thanks for answer but how and why only on one page?

Comment: Maybe try setting `default_charset = "utf-8"` in your php.ini?

Comment: Take a look into `http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php`

Comment: to geruetzel:
Same php used on every page
Im creating some text and picture galleries No problem on other pages

Comment: Did you set the PHP header and file-encoding to be UTF-8 too? I'd start there.

Comment: to Qirel: no need to it worked on previous pages
But i tryed anyway, nothing happend

Comment: At the very top of your `.php` files, before anything else, add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` directly after `<?php`.

Comment: No Qirel this changes nothing, Im familiar whit this and tried once more. No efects
Thanks for helping anyway

Comment: Check the file-encoding of your files, too. Is it static data, or are you pulling it from a database?

Comment: I implement just a html part, when check already have a problem
im not put php at all
The previous page have a same html, javasqript and php codes and is still good